# Problen with Vue Html2pdf File Name

Tags: vue.js, pdf, html2pdf

I have a Vue 2 project (with Vuetify) and vue-html2pdf in a component
I must print to screen and download a pdf and i do this:

```
<vue-html2pdf
  ref="html2Pdf"
  :show-layout="false"
  :enable-download="false"
  preview-modal
  manual-pagination
  :pdf-quality="2"
  pdf-format="a4"
  pdf-orientation="portrait"
  :html-to-pdf-options="{
    filename: `Name.pdf`,
    margin: [8, 8, 8, 8]
  }"
>
  <div slot="pdf-content" class="pdf-order">
    <section class="pdf-order-header">
      <p>Order N. {{ order.number }}</p>
    </section>
  </div>
</vue-html2pdf>
```

It's work fine, but why the filename is something like `6dded5fa-26ac-4ce5-bf24-d85fb3365dcd.pdf` and not `Name.pdf`?

Answer (score 0):

You must specify props "filename". Like this:

```
<vue-html2pdf
  ref="html2Pdf"
  :show-layout="false"
  :enable-download="false"
  preview-modal
  manual-pagination
  :pdf-quality="2"
  pdf-format="a4"
  pdf-orientation="portrait"
  filename: "Name"
>
  <div slot="pdf-content" class="pdf-order">
    <section class="pdf-order-header">
      <p>Order N. {{ order.number }}</p>
    </section>
  </div>
</vue-html2pdf>
```

Or if you want to use html-to-pdf-option, you must specify your compomente like this:

```
  <vue-html2pdf
  ref="html2Pdf"
  :show-layout="false"
  :enable-download="false"
  preview-modal
  manual-pagination
  :pdf-quality="2"
  pdf-format="a4"
  pdf-orientation="portrait"
  :htmlToPdfOptions="{
    filename: `Name.pdf`,
    margin: [8, 8, 8, 8]
  }"
>
  <div slot="pdf-content" class="pdf-order">
    <section class="pdf-order-header">
      <p>Order N. {{ order.number }}</p>
    </section>
  </div>
</vue-html2pdf>
```